# Media queries don't work after compiled with Webpack from SCSS

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I've got the following SCSS stylesheet

```
.Header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 565px) {
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
  }

  &__Nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-around;

    @media screen and (max-width: 565px) {
      flex-flow: column;
    }

    &--left { order: 0; }

    &--right { order: 2; }
  }

  &__Logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    order: 1;

    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
      order: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The media queries are present in the compiled code, but just seem not to be applied, since when resizing the window the `flex-flow` properties are not changed as well as item order. What can cause this problem?

**UPDATE** -- I've updates SCSS and compiled code in the link. Still, it doesn't work as expected.

**UPDATE 2** -- The problem was solved and the links were deleted. It was the problem with my classes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webpack config is fine. The media queries are at line 75: https://pastebin.com/CcTQy39W

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .Header {
        -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
        flex-flow: column wrap
    }

    .Header__Logo {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -ms-flex-order: 0;
        order: 0
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 595px) {
    .Header {
        -webkit-box-pack:stretch;
        -ms-flex-pack: stretch;
        justify-content: stretch
    }
```

Comment: yes, the problem is that they don't work. the order of items when resizing the window isn't changed, as well as the `flex-flow`. what can cause this?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 this is simply because of your CSS, and it's nothing to do with webpack.

Comment: then could you tell me please what's wrong with my css? btw I've posted an update

Comment: can you make a new question for that, as it's a completely different question. also considered making a example that people can play with that includes the url.